# SCP (using sshj) from remote HP-UX (Unix) server to local file system

Tags: java, unix, scp, hp-ux, sshj

I want to perform a remote copy of data from a **remote HP-UX server** to my local file system using the [sshj](https://github.com/hierynomus/sshj) library.

The data on this remote server has the form: `DATA_<YEAR>.dat`.  For example:

```
DATA_1998.dat
DATA_1999.dat
DATA_2000.dat
DATA_2001.dat
DATA_2002.dat
```

The specific method I'm using is the following:

```
SSHClient.newSCPFileTransfer().download(String remotePath, LocalDestFile localFile)
```

**Given a starting and ending year (i.e. `1991` and `2001`), how can I construct a `String` to pass as the `remotePath` parameter to copy the range of files between the given start and end years?**

Comment: If any further clarification is needed, I'm happy to provide more details.

Comment: You should consider using the SFTP protocol instead of SCP. SFTP would let you get a list of files in the remote directory and then retrieve the files that you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Generate each filename individually and then copy one by one.

```
final int START = 1998;
final int END = 2001;
for (int y = START; y <= END; y++) {
    final String year = "DATA_" + y;
    System.out.println(year);
}
```

Otherwise you could try separating the files by a comma or space to see if that works.